# Can I split my JKS into a private key and public certificate pair?

Tags: windows, java, android

I have managed to make a [Java Keystore](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjT6pS245bVAhVK5mMKHaIbBFwQFggWMAM&usg=AFQjCNHRGWe2dHUkir3wbVu-mosgkVfvZA) for my android development platform, but I need to split the keystore into a private key and public key. If I understand correctly, I should be able to split the keystore into files like this:

```
Private Key.pk8
```

and

```
Public Certificate.x509.pem
```

I used [KeyStore Explorer](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://keystore-explorer.org/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiPuKGH5JbVAhUQzGMKHbpIDaEQFggQMAI&usg=AFQjCNGRK0okm--mccxD-UdomgbE2wuS6g) to make my keystore. I have looked this up, but the explanations I find are too vague or are not constructed very well. Is there a way to do this, and if so, can it be done in KeyStore Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly used this code and following steps to generate the respected files

1. Copy the abc.jks (assuming you have abc.jks file with you) in the bin folder of java
2. Open CMD and set the path to bin folder of java
3. Copy the below code to convert the abc.jks to pfx format
   `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc.jks -srcstoretype jks -destkeystore abc.pfx -deststoretype pkcs12`
4. Now you will have an abc.pfx file with you which need to be converted into pem format
5. Download OpenSSL from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads)
6. Copy the abc.pfx file in the bin folder of OpenSSL
7. Change the path in CMD to bin folder of OpenSSL
8. Below is the code for to convert abc.pfx in pem
   `openssl pkcs12 -in abc.pfx -out abc.pem`
9. Now you will have an abc.pem file with you which has the key and the certificates in it
10. Copy the 1st content into a new notepad which is the key file and rename it to key.pk8 (.pk8 is the extension)(content will look like this)
    **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAjkC85S808AcrviwX5BYresTSTBmt1DTeVCutG699fI91ykHE
    at56T8SqCLtd6BunOeYJEdM6kSc6P+6gNI1xTW+ULP3Kf+2rRKyElVCPfJ43jRJW

    .

    .

    .

    2TXNgIsangK/PWSSBZhX8EVxMV5Or60UkUU7k62bCLaxuq6nnvIKtp7DCXMjlnfS
    wiP7mUebMR9AsuY4YlnYFCqHy/7UgHdIWSPW4zFzo8dBbdxOrl0gZw==
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**
11. Copy the remaining content to a new notepad and rename it filename.pem (.pem is the extension)(the remaining content will look like this)
    **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAjkC85S808AcrviwX5BYresTSTBmt1DTeVCutG699fI91ykHE
    at56T8SqCLtd6BunOeYJEdM6kSc6P+6gNI1xTW+ULP3Kf+2rRKyElVCPfJ43jRJW

    .

    .

    .

    2TXNgIsangK/PWSSBZhX8EVxMV5Or60UkUU7k62bCLaxuq6nnvIKtp7DCXMjlnfS
    wiP7mUebMR9AsuY4YlnYFCqHy/7UgHdIWSPW4zFzo8dBbdxOrl0gZw==
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**
    **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAjkC85S808AcrviwX5BYresTSTBmt1DTeVCutG699fI91ykHE
    at56T8SqCLtd6BunOeYJEdM6kSc6P+6gNI1xTW+ULP3Kf+2rRKyElVCPfJ43jRJW

    .

    .

    .

    2TXNgIsangK/PWSSBZhX8EVxMV5Or60UkUU7k62bCLaxuq6nnvIKtp7DCXMjlnfS
    wiP7mUebMR9AsuY4YlnYFCqHy/7UgHdIWSPW4zFzo8dBbdxOrl0gZw==
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**
    **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAjkC85S808AcrviwX5BYresTSTBmt1DTeVCutG699fI91ykHE
    at56T8SqCLtd6BunOeYJEdM6kSc6P+6gNI1xTW+ULP3Kf+2rRKyElVCPfJ43jRJW

    .

    .

    .

    2TXNgIsangK/PWSSBZhX8EVxMV5Or60UkUU7k62bCLaxuq6nnvIKtp7DCXMjlnfS
    wiP7mUebMR9AsuY4YlnYFCqHy/7UgHdIWSPW4zFzo8dBbdxOrl0gZw==
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**

If you are using the **Keystore Explorer** then kindly follow the following steps

1. Open the abc.jks file using Keystore Explorer
2. Right-click on the entry name, select export, then click on export private key and then select the **pkcs #8**
3. Enter the password and then change the extension to key**.pk8** (this is your required private key)
4. Again, right-click on the entry name, select export, select export certificate chain, select entire chain length, pkcs #7, PEM and then export

you will have all the require files at the end